# How can I prevent parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the below error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

I do no know why it is happening. So could someone maybe point me in the right direction? It works on localhost with mamp... but when I try to use Nodejs to run the server... that is when I get the error. The code in which it is related to is below.

```
function e(a) {
    var b = c.console || {}, e = b[a] || b.log || H;
    a=!1;
    try {
        a=!!e.apply
    } catch (l) {}
    return a ? function() {
        var a = [];
        return s(arguments, function(b) {
            a.push(d(b))
        }), e.apply(b, a)
    } : function(a, b) {
        e(a, null == b ? "" : b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late, but still might help someone.

I do not see the code that does something like `XMLSerializer.serializeToString(node)`, which is actually throwing the error. It's saying the parameter that was passed to it, was not a `DOM node`.

For example, I had this issue because (on browser) I was passing a jQuery object instead of a node.

```
const myNode = $('#myElement');
const data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(myNode);
// ^ it throws error here because myNode is not a DOM node. To fix
const myNode = $('#myElement').get(0);
```